# Global variable is not getting updated from within a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

I am creating a simple form where user can set the hour.
Through javascript validation it checks that there is a value in the form.
Originally the global variable "userInputHours" is set to 0.

Within the function "validation()" when user fullfills the required criteria of filling in something in the form, the validation goes to "else" and should update global variable "userInputHours".

As a last step the HTML info-box should update the user input hours.

**What is the problem?** I cannot get the user form input value to stay on the HTML info-box (it is visible for less than a second, then it gets overwritten by the original value "userInputHours").

I know some answer would indicate I should use AJAX but that is to solve that only parts of the page is being reloaded. Using AJAX does not solve the base of my problem.

**Scenarios and what works/don't work:**

---

**Scenario-1:** Enter digits in form field "hours" and press button "submit-1":

---

**Works:** Console log prints "You added: [the number you added in HTML form].

**Does not work:** Running a console.log(userInputHours) from console itself returns the originally value [0] not the user added value. Note! For a very short moment, less than a second you actually see the user value in the HTML form but to be overwritten by original value.

**Wanted results:** In HTML info-box the number user added should show up.

---

**Scenario-2:** Pressing submit-2 calls function "outsideValidation()", 
that set's "userInputHours" to 5:

---

**Works:** the global variable "userInputHours" is being updated from within the function. The console.log(userInputHours) confirmes that global variable has been updated. The HTML info-box is being updated with the update global variabl value.

**Does not work:** Since this test is not connected to the user form field "hours", it does not work to add a number in the field "hours" and get it updated onf the HTML info-box.

**Expected results:** Works as expected. Does not solve the complete needed solution.

```js
// Global variables.
var userInputHours = 0;

// Validation.
function validation() {

userInputHours = document.getElementById("userInputHours").value; // Works

  /* Validates blank fields */
  if (userInputHours == "") {
    console.log("A field is left blank"); // Works
    alert("Please fill in all fields!") // Works
    return false;
  }

    else {
      console.log("You added: " + userInputHours); // Works
      // You see added value for a very short moment. The it returns to the original glbal value.
      document.getElementById("info-box-text").innerHTML = userInputHours; // Does not work.
      return true;
  }
}

/* Not part of validation. Connected to button "submit-2" */
function outsideValidation() {
userInputHours = 5;
document.getElementById("info-box-text").innerHTML = userInputHours; // Works but is disconnected from HTML form user input.
}


/* Not part of function. Only run when saving the script. */
document.getElementById("info-box-text").innerHTML = userInputHours; // Works by save the script.
```

```css
.box-1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#userInputHours {
  width: 100px;
}

#submit-1,
#submit-2 {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit = "return validation();">

 Hours:<br />
 <input id="userInputHours" type="text" name="hours" value=""><br /><br />

 <input id="submit-1" type="submit" value="Submit-1 (inside form)"><br /><br /> <!-- Submit button -->

</form>

<br />

<input id="submit-2" type="submit" value="Submit-2 (outside form)" onclick="outsideValidation()">

<br /><br />
<div id="info-box-title" class="info-box-title">Info-box - (you have set hours to):<br /></div>
<div id="info-box-text" class="info-box-text"></div>
```

Comment: _“You see added value for a very short moment. The it returns to the original glbal value.”_ - well in roughly 11 out of 10 cases that simply means the browser submitted your form the normal way, so the page simply “reloads”. And since you are returning `true` from inside your validation function in this case, this is nothing but to be expected here in this instance as well.

Comment: The `return true` after `document.getElementById("info-box-text").innerHTML = userInputHours; // Does not work.`  tells the browser, that it is allowed to submit the form, so it will set the `innerHTML` which will be visible for a short moment until the browser was able to submit the data. Because no `action` attribute is specified the target url of the submit is the current url, and the page is reloaded. So do you want to submit the data to the server in this case or not?

Comment: In this specific test I do not need to submit the data to a server. The code is part of an alarm to a javascript digital clock. Basically the user should be able to add "HH-MM-ss" and the reason it should be send to the HTML "info-box" is to have the confirmation of what time the user set the alarm.

Comment: Well then change the `return true` to `return false` and everything should work as expected. If you want to send it to the server and keep the information, then you either need to use ajax to send the data, while staying on the page. Or the server has submit all information you need with the response to the form submit.

Comment: @t.niese: Your suggestion works. Could you elaborate a bit of howcome setting it to "return false" works. My understanding is that it is the "return true" that normally gets triggered. If you create an answer I can approve it as a solution to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `validation` is used by the browser to determine if the default behavior of the form submit should be done.

If the return value is `true` then the default behavior will take place, and the browser will submit the form to the URL which is defined in the `action` attribute (if no value is present for the `action` attribute then it defaults to the current url).

With a form submit you will leave the current page and load a new one or reload the current one depending on the value of `action`. And because of that all value stored with js are lost.

If you do not want to send the data to the server you have to write `return false` in both cases to prevent the form submit.